# Xamarin Native Android LinearLayout weight applied to a children weird problem

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I would like to have the following output. I am giving my code and an image which shows how it currently looks like. I am using MVVMCross with Xamarin Nativ UI for Android.

**Required output** The top view should take 70% of the space and the below should take 30% of the available space.

The current layout is used in a fragment. So this layout is added as a child to a the framelayout in the activity, hosting this fragment.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".7">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:gravity="top"            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Add Entry"
            local:MvxBind="Click AddCommand"            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/waves"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MilliliterViewContainer"/> <!-- The ml is a custom view which is being inflated and added in this layout from the code behind -->

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the current output, it somehow applied the weight on the child, which is imageview.

**Current Output** I don't understand why does the image is not being shown in full width? why weight is applied to the image view width? The waves is a vector image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scale type on an `ImageView` in Android is `fitCenter`, which seems to tell the Vector Drawable to just kind of fit the height in the center.

If you switch to `fitXY` it will fill the width.

I also suggest that you re-work your layout to use `ConstraintLayout` instead to avoid using expensive weights on `LinearLayout`. This could look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waves_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/waves"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:text="Add Entry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overview"
        android:text="Overview Text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This flattens the layout significantly, meaning less overdraw and less calculations done to calculate the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I cannot use constraint layout, as it is not available in Xamarin Native

Comment: Yes it is available through nuget packages